# JavaScript Bind, Apply, and the `this` pointer

Tags: javascript, currying

I got a little confused with JS `bind`, `apply`, and `this`.

**Questions**

- Why are `this` and `null` interchangeable in the following snippet?
- Does `this` in the following context point to the `window`?

```js
function curry(fn) {
  // your code here
  return function curryInner(...args) {
    if (args.length >= fn.length) return fn.apply(this, args);
    return curryInner.bind(this, ...args);  //change this to null, still pass the test
  };
  
}
const join = (a, b, c) => {
   return `${a}_${b}_${c}`
}

const curriedJoin = curry(join)

console.log(curriedJoin(1, 2, 3)) // '1_2_3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `this` points to the `this` context of the function it is in.

In this case, it really doesn't matter what you put there since the only purpose of calling `bind` is to create a copy of the function with the args already set.

```js
return curryInner.bind(null, ...args)
```

could essentially be replaced with

```js
return function() {
  return curryInner(args);
}
```